# Can't make google maps v2 to work

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I tried a lot of examples but still can't get it to work!
I have a grid with no maps and "  couldn't get connection factory client".

I tried [here](http://android-er.blogspot.gr/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) and [here](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435) and many others.
I tried to run it and on device but still the same.

Any ideas here?Any other good tutorial?

Thank you!

Comment: check your internet connection and api key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have tried my tutorial. The problem you describe usually happens when there is a problem with your key.

Please go over the next tutorial as well for getting your key:

[Google Map API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

it this doesn't help you, try to delete the `debug.keystore` folder and run any android project to recreate a new key, and perform all the process of associating your key to your project using the console all over again.

And check again that you are adding all the permissions from the first tutorial in you manifest file.

Comment: :before doing that, can you please give me a code for MainActivity ?To check if it works?Thanks

Comment: if your read carefully: "8. Now create an Activity that extends from “FragmentActivity” , create an XML layout file
for this activity and set it as the content View of this activity, in the layout write the following:". so all you need to do is to create a FragmentActivity and set the setContentView to the layout that is described in the tutorial.

Comment: :Ok, i did that .Also , I deleted the debug.keystore folder.The API key from google is still the same.Now,i have this problem.If i run it on my device it gives me "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.","You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!","Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.mymap' in a shell.".I executed adb uninstall and installed again the device but still the same!What to do now?

Comment: :If i run it on the emulator it gives me "This app won't run without Google Play services,which are missing from your phone"

Comment: :Ok, it works now!I run through device and i did update Google Play services.Now , its ok,thanks!

Comment: Great you managed to figure it out, @George, have a nice coding : )

Comment: :Thanks!I am trying now to tun it with "MapActivity" instead of "FragmentActivity" but it gives me an empty grid with this.Do you know sth that will help me?

Comment: @ Emil Adz:Ok, i found it , Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

this occurs when you use different key for the app in the manifest than the actual google project key. Try rechecking the key. I had the same problem, and figured it out the same way. It has nothing to deal with the code. Good Luck!

Comment: I have one api key for debugging and that's I use.

Comment: The answer below by @Emil Adz is correct. This is just due to the mismatch of keys.