# App shows grid screen instead of google map

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to get a basic map application to work but, I am getting only the grid screen.

**Code:**

1.ActivityMain.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);       

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

2.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true" 
  android:enabled="true" 
  android:apiKey="[api_key]" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

3.Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vevolet.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.vevolet.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.vevolet.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="[api_key]" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I also tried this code with api generated using the keystore generated from the application..but it did not work.

Please tell me what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: using google maps api v2?

Comment: How did you generate the API KEY ?

Comment: @raghu-yes and I generated it using google api console

Comment: can you post you layout xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel pretty stupid answering my own question(esp. with a bounty on it) but I'm doing it anyway.

`Raghunandan` and `Emil Adz` solved the first mistake I did(of mixing gmaps v1 and v2 code), thank you guys. 
But then I encountered two other problems:

**Problem 1:** The library was failing to link with my project.
**Problem 2:** I was getting an error "error inflating the class fragment"

Solution:

**For Problem 1:** I copied the `google-play-services_lib` folder inside `C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject` and pasted it into another drive and then imported it from the new location and referenced it to my project.

**For Problem 2:** I replaced the `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment` in  inside `<fragment>`(inside my activity xml) which is for the native API Level 11 edition of fragments.

Comment: glad you could solve your problem. thanks for awarding the bounty. in case you run into problem will be glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

This is because you mixing up both API version of Google Maps. On one hand you are using `MapView` which is an `API V1` object on the other hand you have produced your key for `API V2` and using the permissions for this version.

So because `API V1` is deprecated and no longer available and because you are on half way to implement `Google Maps API V2` what you should do is:

**1.** Remove this permission, as it's a API V1 permission:

```
 <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

**2.** Replace this code in your xml:

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map_view"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:clickable="true" 
 android:enabled="true" 
 android:apiKey="[api_key]" />
```

whit this one:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**3.** Remove this line from your java code:

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
```

You can take a look at this guide I wrote on Google Maps API V2 to get the full idea of it's implementation:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: I tried it but am getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vevolet.maps.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.vevolet.maps-1.apk]" this error

Answer (score 1):

Your min sdk is 8. You should use Support Fragment.

Instead of this

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true" 
android:enabled="true" 
android:apiKey="[api_key]" />
```

Use the below

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Your activity must extend `FragmentActivity`. Will be using SupportFragment

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = fm.getMap();
```

Make sure you have added support library

Also make sure you imported the below

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Also if you have updated adt to rev 22

Right click on your project goto properties. Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. If you have referenced library project. do the same for the google play services library project also. Clean and Build.

You can remove this as suggested by EmilAdz

```
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Make sure you have followed the steps in the below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Also **make sure you have enabled maps for android in google api console under the services tag**.

Test in on a device.

Edit:

You should refer to google services library project in your map project

Download the Google Play services.Goto Windows. Goto Android Sdk Manager. Choose Google play services under extras. If not installed install the package.

Copy the google-play services_lib library project to your workspace. The library project can be found under the following path.

```
<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project .
```

Import the library project to your eclipse.

Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse the workspace import the library project. You can check if it is library project. Right click on the library project. Goto properties. Click Android on the left panel. You will see Is Library checked.

To refer to the library project

Right click on you android map project. goto properties. Choose Android. Click Add borwse and add the library project.

Comment: Im getting this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Comment: can you tell how did you refer to the library project?

Comment: @jaisonDavis try the edit my guess you have not referred to the google services library project properly

Comment: I got an error when I tried to add one of the import, eclipse offered to add the lib as a solution..thats how I added it

Comment: what was the procedure you followed. did you follow the steps mentioned in the edit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31807/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-jaisondavis)

Comment: can you post the updated code and move the discussion to chat

Answer (score 0):

Which certificate did you use to generate the API key? If you launch from Eclipse, your apk is signed with a debug certificate, not your release certificate, so you need a different API key for the debug keystore.

See [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Comment: I got SHA1 while signing the app's and I also tried it using the default keystore

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer--

[Can't make google maps v2 to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474241/cant-make-google-maps-v2-to-work/15474264#15474264)

This occurs when the key of your google project does not match with the one you specify in the manifest. Do go through all the directed steps again, and check your key.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem , it works for me when I tested in device with openGL 2.0. But when I tested in version 2.2.1 it shows only the grid screen, due to lack of openGL2.0. But I used SupportMapFragment instead MapView in XML as specified by google-maps-api-v2 documentation. Also ensure google play services get's updated before testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have few different applications that uses Google Maps and only one of them has problem similar to yours, next solution helped me:

1. Go to [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
2. Open API Access tab
3. Choose "Create New Android key"
4. Use new generated API key in your AndroidManifest.xml